# Unable to start solr service

Tags: java, solr

I seem to be unable to start a solr serer on port 8983..

Everytime i try to access it, I get this error message:

```
C:\sitecore\solr-6.6.2\bin>solr.cmd -p 8983
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseParNewGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Waiting up to 30 to see Solr running on port 8983
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.eclipse.jetty.util.BufferUtil (file:/C:/sitecore/solr-6.6.2/server/lib/jetty-util-9.3.14.v20161028.jar) to field java.nio.MappedByteBuffer.fd
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.eclipse.jetty.util.BufferUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

ERROR: Solr at https://localhost:8983/solr did not come online within 30 seconds!
```

Which is weird as this port seem to be standard for solr services?

Comment: I'm not seeing any error messages in your post; I see WARNING messages but no indication that something isn't functioning.

Comment: added error. mesage

Answer (score 0):

Its the issue with java 9 and solr trying to start with that,  so that you are getting this waring. based on your solr version please choose the java version. I hope this will be solved it.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is part of Java 9 changes and has been described in [SOLR-8689](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-8689) (see last couple of comments.

Don't use Java 9 with your version of Solr or update Solr to the latest.

Answer (score 0):

- Download solr + copy downloaded folder to c: drive (solr7.2.1)
- Download nssm installer + copy downloaded folder to  c: drive (solr)
- open nssm installer in cmd:

  ```
            >> cd C:\solr\nssm2.24\win64
            >> nssm install solr7
  ```
- GUI service Installer opens (Enter solr path details)

  ```
  - C:\solr-7.2.1\bin\solr.cmd
  - C:\solr-7.2.1\bin
  ```
- Install (solr as service gets installed)
- Set Environment Variable -> System Variables (JRE Path):

  ```
  JAVA_HOME: c:\ProgramFiles\java\jre1.8.0_212
  ```
- Check if solr is running (from services)
- Open Solr:
  https://localhost:8983/solr/#/